# Unique Positive Number Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

What is the value that appears at each of the following positions in this sequence?

(a) 411 (b) 1000 (c) 1245

Source - Zonal Informatics Olympiad 2005 Question Paper

Comment: Golomb's sequence: http://oeis.org/A001462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple program:

```
 N:= 1245: A[1]:= 1: B[1]:= 1: A[2]:= 2: 
 for n from 2 while B[n-1] <= N do 
   B[n]:= B[n-1] + A[n];
   for j from B[n-1]+1 to B[n] do A[j]:= n end do
 end do:
 A[411],A[1000],A[1245];
```

$$ 50, 86, 98$$